# How to specify initial sorting order as descending using tablesorter function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, tablesorter

I have changed sortInitialOrder:"asc" to sortInitialOrder:"desc" in tablesorter jquery file ,but it doesn't work.When I click on the column headers, the first sort is still in ascending order.

How can I get sorting order descending on first click? how to initialize that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
$("table").tablesorter({ 
        // sort on the 1st column and 3rd column, order asc 
        sortList: [[0,0],[2,0]] 
    });
```

Comment: Not sure why this is the answer... the question is actually about `sortInitialOrder`, not `sortList`.

Comment: @Mottie, exactly! The same problem just came up for me.

Answer (score 3):

I found this question trying to solve the same problem, and answers here doesn't really help.

For the problem in the OP you actually need apply [sortInitialOrder](https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/index.html#sortinitialorder) option. 
[Example](https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-options-headers-order.html). You could also override this for any particular header using [headers](https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/index.html#headers) option.

```
  $("table").tablesorter({
    sortInitialOrder: "asc",

    headers: {
      0: { sortInitialOrder: 'desc' }
    }

  });
```

I've just implemented a simple function doing this thing for my project. So let me show what I did.

```
function headers(headersCount, ascOrderCols, noSorterCols, noFilterCols) {
    let headers = {}

    for (let column = 0; column < headersCount; column++) {
        headers[column] = {}
        if (noSorterCols.includes(column)) {
            headers[column]['sorter'] = false
        };
        if (noFilterCols.includes(column)) {
            headers[column]['filter'] = false
        };
        if (ascOrderCols.includes(column)) {
            headers[column]['sortInitialOrder'] = 'asc'
        };

    };
    return headers;
};

let ascOrderCols = [...Array(11).keys()];
let headersCount = $("#tab1 > thead > tr:first > th").length;

$("#tab1")
  .tablesorter({
      sortInitialOrder: 'desc',
      headers: headers(headersCount, ascOrderCols, [0], [0, 1, 2]),
})
```

You could also use a table data insted of global variables.

```
$("#tab1").data('ascOrderCols', [...Array(11).keys()]);
$("#tab1").data('headersCount', $("#tab1 > thead > tr:first > th").length);

headers: headers($("#tab1").data('headersCount'), $("#tab1").data('ascOrderCols'), [0, 5], [0, 1, 2]),
```

Comment: Personally, I don't use the `headers` option. Instead, I set the class name in the header to accomplish the same thing - [demo](https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-parsers-class-name.html).

Answer (score 1):

As the others already said, you must use the `sortList` option when starting the `tablesorter`.

> How can I get sorting order descending on first click?

A: By initializing all of them sorted by ascending order, e.g:

```
$('#tablesorter-demo').tablesorter({
  sortList: [[0,0], [1,0], [2,0], [3,0], [4,0], [5,0] /* as many columns as you have */]
});
```

It's `sortList` parameter is an Array, and each item of this Array is an Array with a 2-length, and its first item is the column index, and the second one is `0` for ascending, and `1` for descending.

I've created a snippet to show you how to achieve what you want:

```css
/* tables */
table.tablesorter {
 font-family:arial;
 background-color: #CDCDCD;
 margin:10px 0pt 15px;
 font-size: 8pt;
 width: 100%;
 text-align: left;
}
table.tablesorter thead tr th, table.tablesorter tfoot tr th {
 background-color: #e6EEEE;
 border: 1px solid #FFF;
 font-size: 8pt;
 padding: 4px;
}
table.tablesorter thead tr .header {
 
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-position: center right;
 cursor: pointer;
}
table.tablesorter tbody td {
 color: #3D3D3D;
 padding: 4px;
 background-color: #FFF;
 vertical-align: top;
}
table.tablesorter tbody tr.odd td {
 background-color:#F0F0F6;
}
table.tablesorter thead tr .headerSortUp:after {
 content: " ▼";
}
table.tablesorter thead tr .headerSortDown:after {
 content: " ▲";
}
table.tablesorter thead tr .headerSortDown, table.tablesorter thead tr .headerSortUp {
background-color: #8dbdd8;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://tablesorter.com/__jquery.tablesorter.min.js"></script>
<table id="tablesorter-demo" class="tablesorter" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="1">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>First Name</th>
      <th>Last Name</th>
      <th>Age</th>
      <th>Total</th>
      <th>Discount</th>
      <th>Difference</th>
      <th>Date</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Peter</td>
      <td>Parker</td>
      <td>28</td>
      <td>$9.99</td>
      <td>20.9%</td>
      <td>+12.1</td>
      <td>Jul 6, 2006 8:14 AM</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>John</td>
      <td>Hood</td>
      <td>33</td>
      <td>$19.99</td>
      <td>25%</td>
      <td>+12</td>
      <td>Dec 10, 2002 5:14 AM</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Clark</td>
      <td>Kent</td>
      <td>18</td>
      <td>$15.89</td>
      <td>44%</td>
      <td>-26</td>
      <td>Jan 12, 2003 11:14 AM</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Bruce</td>
      <td>Almighty</td>
      <td>45</td>
      <td>$153.19</td>
      <td>44.7%</td>
      <td>+77</td>
      <td>Jan 18, 2001 9:12 AM</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Bruce</td>
      <td>Evans</td>
      <td>22</td>
      <td>$13.19</td>
      <td>11%</td>
      <td>-100.9</td>
      <td>Jan 18, 2007 9:12 AM</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Bruce</td>
      <td>Evans</td>
      <td>22</td>
      <td>$13.19</td>
      <td>11%</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>Jan 18, 2007 9:12 AM</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<script>
  $('#tablesorter-demo').tablesorter({
    sortList: [[0,0], [1,0], [2,0], [3,0], [4,0], [5,0], [6,0]] // comment this
    //sortList: [[0,1], [1,1], [2,1], [3,1], [4,1], [5,1], [6,1]] // and uncomment this for starting all of them desc
  });
</script>
```